# Unable to select data from AWS Athena table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have created a table in Athena using below SQL

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xyzschema.my_table (
  `col1` string,
  `col2` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = ',',
  'field.delim' = ','
) LOCATION 's3://temp/my_table_data/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Post creation of table when I try to query from the table

```
select 'col1' from "my_table"
```

I am getting the following error , not really sure what permission is missing

Your query has the following error(s):

```
Insufficient permissions to execute the query. Principal does not have any privilege on specified resource
```

If I run the following

```
select * from "gleif_data_master_csv"
```

I get the below error

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed in queries without FROM clause
```

Any suggestions/ideas why this is breaking ?

Comment: Is your data really stored in an Amazon S3 with a bucket name of `temp`? Can you run the SELECT commands without using any single/double quotation marks?

Comment: can you post some sample records from your data?

Comment: I was able to query the table created using same DDL as in your question

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - No its not really stored in temp , I have just replaced actual names with temp, but the bucket and the underlying key do exist , if I try to query without quotes I get the same error.

Comment: The user who runs an Amazon Athena query also requires sufficient permission to access the objects being queried from Amazon S3. Do you have permission to access those S3 objects?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - just to add about the storage - s3://temp/my_table_data/  , temp is the bucket and my_table_data is the folder which has multiple csv files partitioned on Date (so one file for each day). Not sure on how could I check the permission , I can access the S3 bucket and keys from AWS S3 GUI.

Comment: The issue was with the user that was trying to access the table did not have access to that Athena table. It is resolved now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Insufficient permissions to execute the query. Principal does not have any privilege on specified resource

This is a Lake Formation permissions error – the table you are querying is part of a catalog managed by Lake Formation. Look in that service for what permissions your user ("principal" in AWS speak) is allowed to do.

Comment: Athena was only giving me the second error (SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed in queries without FROM clause) but adding Select permission to my IAM user in Lake Formation was exactly the solution.

Athena error reporting leaves a lot to be desired.